# Expectation of the product of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

An urn contains $n$ cards marked from $1$ to $n$. Two cards are drawn at a time. Find the mathematical expectation of the product of the numbers on the cards.

I tried to answer this question and obtained the answer to be $\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$ with replacement.
Is it right?

How to approach it when it is without replacement?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hmm. What is the probability that the product is equal to $k$ (assuming replacement)? Answer: the number of divisors of $k$ divided by $n^2$, or
$$
\frac{ \tau(k)}{n^2}
$$
Now we have to figure out the sum
$$
\mathbb E = \sum_{k=1}^n k \frac{ \tau(k)}{n^2} =  \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k \tau(k)
$$

Comment: Hi! The value of k can exceed n, right? Since it is the product, the maximum value it can take is n^2 with replacement. And it is n(n-1) without replacement.

Comment: ah, of course you are right. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

With replacement, assuming independence:
$$E[N_1N_2]=E[N_1]E[N_2]=\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$$
Without replacement, using the tower property of conditional expectation:
$$\begin{aligned}E[N_1N_2]&=E[E[N_2|N_1]N_1]=\\
&=E\bigg[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k\neq N_1}kN_1\bigg]=\\
&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k \neq j}kj=\\
&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{j=1}^nj\sum_{k \neq j}k=\\
&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{j=1}^nj\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-j\bigg)=\\
&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\bigg(\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bigg)=\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{Thanks @Henry}}{=}\frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{12}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: That last term is $\dfrac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{12}$

Comment: @Henry added it